# How do resize an OS partition

Tags: server, partitioning, mount, virtualization, kvm-virtualization

I am following this [link](https://serverfault.com/questions/594588/how-to-increase-kvm-guest-disk-size-using-lvm-vg-as-storage-pool) to resize my VM disk in KVM.
in my VM host i have updated the disk size shown below.

```
# fdisk -l /dev/vda1
Disk /dev/vda1: 30 GiB, 32211206144 bytes, 62912512 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
```

Further my vm host's disk still shows old space.

```
# df -kh
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/root       7.8G  7.8G     0 100% /
```

I tried to resize using below command but it fails.

```
# sudo resize2fs /dev/vda1
resize2fs 1.42.13 (17-May-2015)
Filesystem at /dev/vda1 is mounted on /; on-line resizing required
old_desc_blocks = 1, new_desc_blocks = 2
resize2fs: Permission denied to resize filesystem
```

I am following [Link](https://arkit.co.in/resize2fs-permission-denied-to-resize-filesystem/) to solve above error. But now getting another errors shown below,

```
# e2fsck -y /dev/vda1
 e2fsck 1.42.13 (17-May-2015)
ext2fs_check_if_mount: Can't check if filesystem is mounted due to missing mtab file while determining whether /dev/vda1 is mounted.
e2fsck: No such file or directory while trying to open /dev/vda1
Possibly non-existent device?


# resize2fs /dev/vda1
resize2fs 1.42.13 (17-May-2015)
ext2fs_check_mount_point: Can't check if filesystem is mounted due to missing mtab file while determining whether /dev/vda1 is mounted.
```

Please let me know what still what i am missing?

Answer (score 1):

The tools say that you cannot fix a file system that is mounted. This means that you cannot change the root file system of the running operating system.

- Instead boot from a live system (it works also in a virtual machine).
- When booted from the live system, you can unmount if necessary and the tools `e2fsck` and `resizefs` should work.
- If you have graphics you can also use the GUI tool `gparted`, which is easier to use in order to resize the partition.